# Como pegar os dados de retorno da api com vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Sou novo usando o Vue.js e estou com um problema para pegar o retorno de uma api. Meu código é o seguinte:

```
div id="app">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="album in albuns">
            {{albuns.Id }} {{albuns.Nome}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<script>
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        albuns: []
    },
    created() {
        fetch('http://localhost:59385/Album/listaralbuns')
            .then(Response => Response.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.albuns = json.albuns
            })
    }
})
</script>
```

Api

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("album/listaralbuns")]
public HttpResponseMessage ListarAlbuns(Album album)
{
    var albumService = new AlbumService();
    var listaAlbuns = albumService.obterAlbum();

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
        listaAlbuns, 
        Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
}
```

A api traz os dados corretos debugando pelo visual studio, mas no retorno os seguintes erros:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:59385/Album/listaralbuns' from origin 'http://localhost:59841' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>
> Teste:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Você está com problema de cors na sua api, como você não postou nenhuma informação da api não tem ajudar. O lado do vue parece estar ok mas primeiro precisa arrumar o lado da api

Comment: olá, eu editei a pergunta colocando também a api do listar, se puder dar uma olhada por favor

Comment: Acho que não fui muito claro, você esta com problema no lado do servidor, quando você faz uma requisição o browser antes de enviar a sua requisição faz uma outra pedindo para o servidor quais "operações" estão liberadas para ele fazer, se a "operação" não estiver liberada o browser vai bloquear a sua chamada, procure no google como liberar o CORS na sua aplicação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os códigos tanto Vue quanto da API estão corretas, o problema que está quando você conecta os dois, o nome disso é CORS.

Por motivos de segurança não é possível fazer requisições de um domínio para outro domínio. Para burlar isso você deve informar que sua API permite esse acesso externo, [nessa página da microsoft eles mostram detalhadamente como fazer isso com C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api).

Basicamente você só precisa adicionar uma linha antes da declaração do seu método para funcionar.

```
...
[EnableCors(origins: "http://www.example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public HttpResponseMessage ListarAlbuns(Album album){
...
```

Comment: Olá desculpe a demora em responder, era o cors mesmo, muito obrigado